# Value of an Array at Index of Another Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays: **string[] files** and **string[] comments**

I am looping through the **files** array using a foreach loop.

```
foreach(string file in files)
{
comments.SetValue(//index of file we are at)
}
```

Say I get to a file which is index 20 of the files array. What I want to do be able to do is get the value of the comments array at the same index. So for files[0] I return comments[0], files[1] comments[1] etc etc.

Comment: Consider using a `Dictionary<string,string>`, perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
   string file = files[i];
   string comment = comments[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do simply:

```
string[] files = { "1", "2", "3" };
            string[] comments = {"a","b","c"};

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                 files[i]  = comments[i] ;
                 i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) assuming that duplicates wont be a problem

```
foreach(string file in files)
{
    int index = files.IndexOf(file);
    //blah blah
}
```

But it would probably be easier and more efficient to use a for loop then you will have the index

```
   for (var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `foreach`, use `for` instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.Zip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) for this:

```
foreach(var fc in files.Zip(comments, (f, c) => new { File = f, Comment = c }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(fc.File);
    Console.WriteLine(fc.Comment);
}
```